# How to solve argument error in Devise Registrations controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use **devise** and **devise token auth** gems. I want to enter edit user path

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path(current_user.id) %>
```

But got an error
**wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)** on this part of code **def authenticate_user!**

```
def authenticate_user!
    if user_signed_in?
      super
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
```

My routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'demo/members_only', to: 'payments#members_only'
  # token auth routes available at /api/v1/auth
  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
  resources :payments
  root "payments#index"
end
```

Now Idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like devise_token_auth redefines basic devise helpers that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `id` of the current user, devise takes current user object from the session, just do this and you are good to go.

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: the same problem `ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#edit
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10
              
  private 

  def authenticate_user!`

Answer (score 0):

If the `current_user` is be used, you don't need to pass it separately. Devise will use it, if no argument is provided.

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path %>
```

What also should work is, if you pass the user record, instead of the `id`:

```
<%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: the same problem `ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#edit wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) private def authenticate_user!`